# How long is support for ROS Hydro?

Tags: ros, roshydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am in doubt to use ROS Hydro for this year in my project at the university, once I dont know for how long the support will continue. I could move to Indigo, but with what I have already developed, it is easier to keep using Hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200960/how-long-is-support-for-ros-hydro?/) by [Gustavo Domingues](https://answers.ros.org/users/21379/gustavo-domingues/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-01-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hydro will officially be EOL'd when Jade comes out. It will keep working, it just won't get updates.

Resources: http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions/Timeline
http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1